# How to set typeattribute in LWC datatable?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, datatable, lwc-dom

```
 {label:'FCU Trigger',   type: "button",
                        typeAttributes: {  
                            label: 'Initiate',  
                            name: 'initiate',  
                            title: 'View',  
                            disabled: false,  
                            value: 'view',  
                            iconPosition: 'left', 
                            variant:"brand",
                            class:"slds-visible" 
                        }},
```

**I want to set class attribute to slds-hidden**

```
obj.typeAttributes.setAttribute('class', 'slds-hidden');
```

**This is not working thrwoing error in console e.typeattribute.setattribute is not a function**

```
 renderedCallback() {

    var table = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
    if(table!= null)
    {
     var rows = table.data;
     var col = table.columns;

            rows.forEach(function(element){
                if(element.SME_Document_Collection_Mode__c === 'Login via link')
                {
                    col.forEach(function(obj){
                        if(obj.label === 'FCU Trigger')
                        {
                            obj.typeAttributes.setAttribute('class', 'slds-hidden');  
                            alert(obj.typeAttributes.class); 
                        }
                    });
                }
                //alert(element);
            });
    }      
}
```

Comment: what is the exact requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to hide the button wherever ***SME_Document_Collection_Mode__c*** is **Login via link**. Modifying the columns will affect the whole table as each object in **columns** define the structure of whole column and not single cell in column.

You can implement one more column at run time which will decide which class to append. Below is the sample:

```
@track columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Mode', fieldName: 'SME_Document_Collection_Mode__c' },
    {
        label: 'FCU Trigger', type: "button",
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Initiate',
            name: 'initiate',
            title: 'View',
            disabled: false,
            value: 'view',
            iconPosition: 'left',
            variant: "brand",
            class: { fieldName: 'ModeClass' }
        }
    }
];

connectedCallback() { // or wire service or any other method where you are getting data
    this.data = this.data.map(record => {
        record.ModeClass = (record.SME_Document_Collection_Mode__c === 'Login via link') ? 'slds-hidden' : 'slds-visible';
        return record;
    });
}
```

Notice the way `class` is getting its value - from another field called **ModeClass** which is being created at run time depending on the field **SME_Document_Collection_Mode__c**.

### [Playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/5yWrpE6wU/4/edit) output:

[image]